# zDepth in Material-UI not working (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Maybe I'dont get it the concept of zDepth. I have component with render method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar
        zDepth={2}
        title="Some title"
        iconElementLeft={<IconButton onClick={this.handleToggle}><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
      />
      <Drawer
        open={this.state.open}
        width={200}
        zDepth={1}>
        <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I  would expect that AppBar will be rendered in front of Drawer. But it doesn't work this way:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1HdO.png)

Comment: have you tried to use just double quotes for the values? `zDepth="2"`

Comment: well I try... not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zDepth` will not help you in this case. The drawer is a bit different from other classic components. If you want your Appbar always in front, you can do the following according to [this issue](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/957):

[Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/app-bar-and-drawer?embed=1&file=index.js)

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar
        zDepth={2}
        title="Some title"
        iconElementLeft={<IconButton onClick={this.handleToggle}><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
      />
      <Drawer
        open={this.state.open}
        width={200}
        zDepth={1}
        style={{ height: AppBar.height }}> // <== HERE
        <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  )
}
```